# How to easily 'interval' login a website and check its content whether has changed?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, verify, uptime

This is a bit high-level solution based question: I have a website, and what I need to do is login->navigate->click category->check whether the specific content has come; every 10 mins.

There are quite a few third-party services, but they only checking the website uptime, which is not what I need.

Currently, I am thinking of silly way: create a selenium UI test, and run it every 10 mins, which seems pretty complex.

Feels like need some tool, so that I can run some extra js on a particular web to test my functionality. Any good solution for this? even some js framework, or even third-party payable service that I can direct make use of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is :

1. Create a selenium test - Single main method that does all the steps.
2. Export it as a runnable jar
3. Schedule the .jar execution using windows scheduler.

Before scheduling the jar, once just double click the .jar file and see if the steps run smoothly.

Alternately you can try using vbscript (.vbs) file also.